# How Do I Update My Html Form Without Refreshing Page In ASP.net?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I've tried to find solutions for quite some time now with no success so I've come to ask here.

I have a ASP.net web application where I get information from a database and put that information in a form on a html page, which works fine. Also I have a search function, which works fine.

But every time I search it reloads the entire page. I know that I should use JQuery...somehow...but I don't really understand how to apply it to my code.

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="log" class="tab active">
        <h1>Log</h1>
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            <p>
                <b>Message:</b> @Html.TextBox("SearchString")
                <input type="button" value="Search" onclick="submit()"/>
            </p>
        }
        @RenderBody()
        @Html.Raw(ViewBag.Data)
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you read any about AJAX?

Comment: You can try looking into an [UpdatePanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001.aspx), which lets you do partial-page updates in ASP.NET. (Which uses AJAX, but handles a lot of stuff for you.)

Comment: [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) is the most common technique for this. On the client side, since you want to use jQuery, then you can make use of [jQuery's AJAX helpers](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). On the server side, you'll need to expose endpoints for your server side functions. In ASP.NET, this is best done with HTTP handlers, generic handlers (.ashx), or [Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api). I would steer clear of UpdatePanel, that is a bad habit to get into, the knowledge isn't transferable to other frameworks and it's difficult to implement properly.

Comment: @Serlite UpdatePanel, aside from all the other reasons against it, isn't usable in MVC.

Comment: @mason That's true, I confess I didn't immediately recognize OP's code as MVC since I haven't used it before.

Comment: There is WebAPI's for MVC in .NET. You can check out this link. http://www.asp.net/web-api

Comment: Hey guys, I'll check this all out now! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lot of ways to do that. 
Simple way is to use normal jquery function to change the data in fields.
Please see the example below for you reference.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/zIMk99

```js
$('.submit').click(function(){
  if($('form').valid()) {
    $.ajax({
      url: '@Url.RouteUrl(new{ action="GetAnswer", controller="Home"})',
      data: {Answer: '', Question: $('#Question').val()},
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      success: function(resp) {
        openAlert(resp);
      }});
  }
  else {
    closeAlert();
  }
});
```

Comment: I tried to make this answer work with my code but couldn't really make it work. Is there any way you could explain it more in detail what all the parts are doing and how I can incorporate it with my code?

Comment: I hope you went through my code in dotnetfiddle.net .. can you reproduce your issue in a fiddle , so that i can try to fix that ..

Comment: Sorry I got really busy with another issue, will get to it today! :)